# Show that, if a, b, c are real numbers and ac = 2(b + d), then at least one of $x^2 + ax + b = 0$ and $x^2 + cx + d = 0$ has real roots.

Tags: algebraic-equations

Show that, if $a, b, c$ are real numbers and $ac = 2(b + d)$, then, at least one of the equations $x^2 + ax + b = 0$ and $x^2 + cx + d = 0$ has real roots.

I've have tried many times and used different methods but can't prove it.

Comment: Include your attempts into the question

Comment: $a,b,c$ are real numbers – fine, but what is $d$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

The sum of discriminants is $$a^2-4b+c^2-4d=a^2+c^2-2ca=(c-a)^2\ge0$$

So, at least one of them  must be $\ge0$